# CSS/HTML - Text on drop down menu goes right even though I aligned it left

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, text-alignment

Picture of the problem I'm having below. I tried googling this but it was such a specific problem that I couldn't find anything helpful.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brSdP.png)
(Sorry for using imgur, Stack overflow doesn't allow new users to embed pictures)

CSS:

```
#dropDown3 {position:absolute;
            top:130px;  
            left:860px;
            padding:15px;
            margin:0px;
            text-align:left;
            line-height:170%;
            width:40px;
            height:45px;
            display:none;
            background-color:#006bb2;
            border-radius:1px;
            z-index:2;}
```

My other two drop-downs are not having this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `left:860px;` , use something lesser like `left:840px;`.

Comment: The CSS you see above is for the entire div, not just the text itself. Aligning it to 840px would mean the drop down would be 20px too far to the right

Comment: Then decrease the `padding`, for example, `padding:15px 0 15px 0;`(top right bottom left).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your padding: You have 15px padding. So because there is too little space, the text appears more at the right side than at the left one.

Try either reducing your padding or set the width a bit larger.

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#dropDown3  li{
 text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your text is left aligned, otherwise the t in Recent and the e in Archive would be aligned right but they are not, as Vucko said, don't move the element as far over to the left.